# GObject Subclassing in Ruby for custom CellRenderer in GtkTreeView

Tags: ruby, gtk, gobject, gtktreeview, cellrenderer

I am trying to implement a customized CellRenderer in Ruby/GTK, and I've already found this suggestion:

[GObject subclassing in Ruby](http://times.usefulinc.com/2006/01/31-subclass)

However, when I try the following:

```
class CellRendererCustom < Gtk::CellRendererText
  type_register #register within gobject system?
  def initialize
    super
  end
  def get_size(widget, cell_area)
    puts "Never called :-("
    return 0,0,100,100
  end
  def signal_do_get_size(widget, cell_area)
    puts "Never called :-("
    return 0,0,100,100
  end
  def signal_do_on_get_size(widget, cell_area)
    puts "Never called :-("
    return 0,0,100,100
  end
  def on_get_size(widget, cell_area)
    puts "Never called :-("
    return 0,0,100,100
  end
end
```

Those signals are never called. I guess there this has something to do with how Ruby is connected to the GObject API, but honestly, I have no idea how this all works.

What I want to do is subclass CellRendererText, and overwrite a method, in this example get_size, which gets called by TreeView. However, I think because CellRendererText is a C Module, and not a ruby class, I cannot overwrite its methods without actually making the system aware of that.

Also I am CellRenderers need to be assigned to a TreeViewColumn, which then calls get_size and other methods.

As far as I know, a similar problem existed in PyGtk, where it was somehow circumvented by adding a `GenericCellRenderer` class:

http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.045.htp

Answer (score 0):

I suspect get_size delegates the `width` and `height` to object properties, and the parent widget uses the properties directly instead of hitting your `get_size` method. `get_size` isn't a signal, which is why `signal_do_get_size` won't get called either.

Try:

```
set_property("width", 100)
```

Comment: I added some clarification to the above question, I actually want to overwrite the get_size method in my subclass.

Comment: I got what you tried to do, and my point stands.
I think get_signal isn't called, neither your implementation nor the implementation in any parent class.
I therefore recommend setting the width and height properties.